# Deny access only for that specific IP which make request more than a limit

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am trying to configure 30 request rate/second for nginx. But I have two question here:

1. Does this configuration blocks the IP address which is making more than 30 request/second or it is 30 request/second inclusive all clients?
2. This 30 request is including inbound and outbound calls or only one way?

Do we have a way to only block the client who is making more number of calls?

```js
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:1m rate=30r/s;
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificate/nginx-certificate.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificate/nginx.key;
  server_name frontend;
  location / {
    limit_req zone=mylimit;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    index index.html index.htm;
  }
}
```